# how to resolve "Kerberos principal name does NOT have the expected hostname part: abcdefg"

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I am attempting to list hfds folder contents with a remote java client as follows:-

```
public class ListHdsfFiles {

    private static final String USER_NAME = "abcdefg";

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", USER_NAME);
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\HADOOP\\hadoop-2.6.0");

        final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.set("hadoop.proxyuser.superuser.hosts", "*");
        configuration.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        configuration.set("hadoop.security.authorization", "true");
        configuration.set("hadoop.security.auth_to_local", "RULE:[1:$1@$0](.*@\\Q\\E$)s/@\\Q\\E$//" + "RULE:[2:$1@$0](.*@\\Q\\E$)s/@\\Q\\E$//" + "DEFAULT");
        configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://host:9000");
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration);


        final UserGroupInformation userGroupInformation = UserGroupInformation.createProxyUser(USER_NAME, UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser());
        final AuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod = AuthenticationMethod.KERBEROS;
        userGroupInformation.setAuthenticationMethod(authenticationMethod);

        userGroupInformation.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<UserGroupInformation>() {

            @Override
            public UserGroupInformation run() throws Exception {

                System.out.println("here ::::: " + UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser());

                final Configuration configurationInner = new Configuration();
                configurationInner.set("hadoop.security.auth_to_local", "RULE:[1:$1@$0](.*@\\Q\\E$)s/@\\Q\\E$//" + "RULE:[2:$1@$0](.*@\\Q\\E$)s/@\\Q\\E$//" + "DEFAULT");
                configurationInner.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://host:9000");
                configurationInner.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
                configuration.set("hadoop.security.authorization", "true");
                configurationInner.set("dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal", USER_NAME);


                final FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configurationInner);
                FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://host:9000/user/abcdefg/sandpit/"));
                for (int i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(status[i].getPath())));
                    String line;
                    line = br.readLine();
                    while (line != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        line = br.readLine();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("--- FINISH ----");

                return UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser();

            }

        });

    }
}
```

i cannot fix this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Kerberos principal name does NOT have the expected hostname part: abcdefg
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.getServerPrincipal(SaslRpcClient.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.createSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:717)
    ... 28 more
```

What hadoop property should i use to set the hostname on my kerberos principal?